# Adding network graph attributes by names of its vertices

Tags: r, igraph

I have a matrix from which I construct a network graph with igraph. I want to store the information of different types of vertices as an attribute, which I can deduce from its names. I tried a couple of combinations

```
mymat = matrix(c(1,0),6,5)
colnames(mymat) <- c("tim", "tom","jane","tarzan", "maria")
rownames(mymat) <- c("tim", "tom","jane","tarzan", "maria", "megan")
M <- graph_from_incidence_matrix(mymat)

V(M)$gender <- ifelse(V(M) == startsWith(as.character(V(M)),"t"), "male","female")
V(M)$gender

[1] "female" "female" "female" "female" "female" "female" "female" "female" "female" "female" "female"
```

I started but forgot to call for the name of the attribute.

```
V(M)
V(M)$name

V(M)$gender <- ifelse(V(M)$name == startsWith(as.character(V(M)$name),"t"), "male","female")
```

Nothing there, too. By accident I called this:

```
V(M)$gender <- ifelse(V(M) == startsWith(as.character(V(M)$name),"t"), "male","female")
V(M)$gender
 [1] "male"   "female" "female" "female" "female" "female" "female" "female" "female" "female" "female"
```

But why not the others, I thought? Seems as it looks only at the first one?

```
V(M)$gender <- ifelse(V(M) == startsWith(as.character(V(M)$name),"to"), "male","female")
V(M)$gender
```

Again, nothing.

1. Is something wrong with how I use ifelse? Do I need to write a function?
2. Is there something wrong with how I call on the attributes' name?
3. off-topic: Why does graph_from_incidence_matrix or igraph in general create a "type"-attribute and on which grounds is "false" and "true" assigned here. You may see it here by

   get.vertex.attribute(M)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert with `igraph`, but I'd like to try answering to the best of my ability. If someone sees this answer and notices something that is incorrect, please do comment so I can fix!

First, it sounds like you wish to identify which vertices start with the letter "t" and assign a `gender` value. Based on `V(M)` you have 11 vertices in your graph:

```
V(M)

+ 11/11 vertices, named, from f5ca776:
 [1] tim    tom    jane   tarzan maria  megan  tim    tom    jane   tarzan maria
```

Some with repeating names.

To first check if the name starts with "t", your code is partially correct here:

```
startsWith(V(M)$name, "t")
# alternative: startsWith(attr(V(M), "names"), "t")

[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

This gives you a logical vector where the `names` attribute starts with "t". And this looks correct.

So, for your `ifelse` statement, you already have the logical value needed to determine `gender`. You don't need to compare this with `V(M)`.

```
M <- set_vertex_attr(M, 
                     "gender", 
                     value = ifelse(startsWith(V(M)$name, "t"), "male", "female"))
M

IGRAPH f5ca776 UN-B 11 15 -- 
+ attr: type (v/l), name (v/c), gender (v/c)
+ edges from f5ca776 (vertex names):
 [1] tim  --tim    tim  --tom    tim  --jane   tim  --tarzan tim  --maria  jane --tim    jane --tom    jane --jane  
 [9] jane --tarzan jane --maria  maria--tim    maria--tom    maria--jane   maria--tarzan maria--maria
```

You now have the attribute created for `gender`:

```
V(M)$gender

[1] "male"   "male"   "female" "male"   "female" "female" "male"   "male"   "female" "male"   "female"
```

Now, you noticed there's the `type` attribute created. Your graph was determined to be bipartite:

```
is_bipartite(M)

[1] TRUE
```

To visualize, you could do the following:

```
plot(M, layout = layout_as_bipartite(M))
```

Or fix up this way based on `type`:

```
V(M)[type]$color <- 'green'
V(M)[!type]$color <- 'yellow'

V(M)$x <- c(rep(1, 6), rep(2, 5))
V(M)$y <- c(seq(1, 5, length.out = 6), seq(1, 5, length.out = 5))

V(M)$label.cex <- .5
V(M)$size <- 30

plot(M)
```

Based on TRUE/FALSE values, we colored by green and yellow and separated spatially.

[image: bipartite plot]